# Flipping an unfair coin 5 times

Tags: probability

I'm flipping an unfair coin 5 times. The probability of getting heads is $\frac{2}{3}$ and the probability of getting tails is $\frac{1}{3}$. What's the probability that at least 3 of the coins end up being heads?

My working:

If I flip 5 times, there are $2^5 = 32$ possible outcomes.

I know that there are $16$ outcomes where there are at least 3 heads (1 with 5H, 5 with 4H, and 10 with 3H).

The probability of getting 0H is $\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^5$. Can I extend this logic for the probability of getting 1H and 2H and simply sum those numbers and subtract from 1?

Comment: See the [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)

Comment: @lulu would the answer in my case be $\binom{32}{16} \cdot (\frac{2}{3})^{16} \cdot (1 - \frac{2}{3})^{32-16}$?

Comment: No.  The probability of getting *exactly* $n$ Heads out of $5$ tosses is $\binom 5n \times p^n\times (1-p)^{5-n}$ where $p$ is the probability of throwing $H$, so $p=\frac 23$ in your case.

Comment: @lulu so I would calculate that probability of getting 3H, 4H, and 5H and sum them together?

Comment: Exactly! $\quad $

Comment: Where did those modestly large exponents in your Comment come from?  You are only flipping the coin five terms, so the exponents in each term of the binomial sum will be five.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A coin flip follows a binomial distribution.
\begin{align*}
P(H\geq3)&=P(H=3)+P(H=4)+P(H=5) \\
&=\binom{5}{3}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^2+\binom{5}{4}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^4\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^1+\binom{5}{5}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^5\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^0\\
&=\frac{64}{81}
\end{align*}